# Sum of first 1000 Prime Numbers in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the sum of first 1000 prime numbers in C# but the code I am using is very slow, takes forever to compute and so far has not returned with a valid sum.

I am new at this and i was hoping any of you guys could have a look and help me make my code efficient and also let me know what I am doing wrong. Also let me know if I am doing anything wrong with regard to the forum rules.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long sumOfPrime=0;

            Console.WriteLine("Calculating Sum of Prime");

            for (int i = 1, primeCounter = 0; primeCounter <= 1000; ++i)
            {
                if (!IsPrime(i)) 
                { 
                    continue; 
                }
                else 
                { 
                    primeCounter = +1; 
                    sumOfPrime = +i; 
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sumOfPrime);
        }

        static bool IsPrime(int number)
        {
            if (number == 1) 
            { 
                return false; 
            }

            if (number == 2) 
            { 
                return true; 
            }

            for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(number)); ++i)
            { 
                if (number % i == 0) 
                { 
                    return false; 
                } 
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, try to find the first 1000 prime numbers first. While doing that, you can output the result, so you can find out a) if getting the numbers works in the first place and b) where the slow down is. Once you've got 1000 numbers in an array or list, summing them should be trivial.

Comment: This question belongs on another site like [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have a look at the various algorithms available to generate prime numbers.  There are faster ones.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes

Comment: use: `+=`  and not: `=+`

Comment: You could use something like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It should be much faster than your current method.

Comment: Use [StopWatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to help determine where your code is taking the longest.

Comment: @Steve Thank you!! Now I see what I was doing and why it felt like my laptop would burn through a hole :)

Comment: @MegaTron Noted,Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @GolezTrol & Nasreddine Thanks Ill try these now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is in:

```
primeCounter = +1
```

This resets the counter every time. I think what you mean is

```
primeCounter += 1
```

... which increments it. Or even better:

```
primeCounter++
```

Answer (score 0):

The following returned 3682913 as the sum of the first 1000 primes and did so in less than a second.  I'm not certain I follow the logic in the for loop of your IsPrime method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Find1000Primes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int totalPrime = 0;
            int countPrime = 1000;
            int x = 0;  // counter for the primes
            int i = 0;  // each number that is checked starting with 0

            while (x < countPrime)
            {
                bool prime = IsPrime(i);
                if (prime)
                {
                    totalPrime = totalPrime + i;
                    x++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(totalPrime.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static bool IsPrime(int number)
        {
            if ((number & 1) == 0)
            {
                if (number == 2)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

            for (int i = 3; (i*i) <= number; i+=2)
            {
                if ((number % i) == 0)
                    return false;
            }
            return number != 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really? The logic of the OP's `IsPrime` method is the same as yours, except for you treating even numbers as a special case, whereas the OP checks for it along with the other possible divisors in the `for` loop.

Comment: What's even better than checking only odd numbers is checking only primes that were previously found; using this approach in C++ on Linux, I was able to get a result almost instantaneously